# xcodebuild "Your session has expired" while trying convert xarchive to .ipa file

Tags: xcodebuild, cicd

I am trying to create a build server for my CICD pipeline.
The problem is whenever I'm trying to run the following command:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath /Users/ec2-user/CICD/Project_path/build/ios/archive/Runner.xcarchive -exportPath /users/ec2-user/CICD/Executions/Build_16-03-22_9:50:45 -exportOptionsPlist "/users/ec2-user/CICD/ExportOptions.plist"
```

for generating a .ipa file the Xcode is repeatedly trying the following process and randomly he succeeds/failed.
These errors could return Succeed after a few times that the Xcode is trying to sign and sometimes will fail.
I am using an AWS instance with 5GB bandwidth so I don't think is a plausible connectivity timeout.

```
2022-03-16 10:04:28.689 xcodebuild[39983:283429] XType: failed to connect - Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.fonts was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.fonts was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
2022-03-16 10:04:28.689 xcodebuild[39983:283429] Font server protocol version mismatch (expected:5 got:0), falling back to local fonts
2022-03-16 10:04:28.689 xcodebuild[39983:283429] XType: unable to make a connection to the font daemon!
2022-03-16 10:04:28.689 xcodebuild[39983:283429] XType: XTFontStaticRegistry is enabled as fontd is not available.
2022-03-16 10:04:28.818 xcodebuild[39983:283429] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path "/var/folders/98/pvj9dycs63q08088386mn_940000gn/T/Runner_2022-03-16_10-04-28.818.xcdistributionlogs".
2022-03-16 10:04:29.371 xcodebuild[39983:283437]  DVTDeveloperAccountManager: Failed to load credentials for yovel@vectoriousmedtech.com: Error Domain=DVTSecErrorDomain Code=-25308 "User interaction is not allowed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=User interaction is not allowed.}
2022-03-16 10:04:29.663 xcodebuild[39983:283437]  DVTPortal: Service '<DVTPortalViewDeveloperService: 0x600003089100; action='viewDeveloper'>' encountered an unexpected result code from the portal ('1100')
2022-03-16 10:04:29.663 xcodebuild[39983:283437]  DVTPortal: Error:
Error Domain=DVTPortalServiceErrorDomain Code=1100 "Your session has expired. Please log in." UserInfo={payload={
    creationTimestamp = "2022-03-16T10:04:29Z";
    httpCode = 200;
    protocolVersion = QH65B2;
    requestUrl = "https://developerservices2.apple.com/services/QH65B2/viewDeveloper.action";
    responseId = "3f6ad022-6b04-4523-bbda-80bbe4c93c3e";
    resultCode = 1100;
    resultString = "Your session has expired. Please log in.";
    userLocale = "en_US";
    userString = "Your session has expired. Please log in.";
}, NSLocalizedDescription=Your session has expired. Please log in.}
2022-03-16 10:04:29.731 xcodebuild[39983:283430]  DVTPortal: Service '<DVTPortalViewDeveloperService: 0x600003054640; action='viewDeveloper'>' encountered an unexpected result code from the portal ('1100')
2022-03-16 10:04:29.731 xcodebuild[39983:283430]  DVTPortal: Error:
Error Domain=DVTPortalServiceErrorDomain Code=1100 "Your session has expired. Please log in." UserInfo={payload={
    creationTimestamp = "2022-03-16T10:04:29Z";
    httpCode = 200;
    protocolVersion = QH65B2;
    requestUrl = "https://developerservices2.apple.com/services/QH65B2/viewDeveloper.action";
    responseId = "2e4cbb16-c62f-42d3-82b0-08f980e37641";
    resultCode = 1100;
    resultString = "Your session has expired. Please log in.";
    userLocale = "en_US";
    userString = "Your session has expired. Please log in.";
},
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Have you found the solution to this issue?

Comment: I am getting same error. Did you get any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet...

Comment: hey, I'm facing the same problem. did you find a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Xcode preferences, and open it.
2. Then press on manage certificates on your main account.
3. Finally press on the add icon (on the bottom left), and choose (Apple Development).

**Your Certificates only need to be updated**

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem also. After hours searching, I cleared the cache/session data under the

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

directories.

It worked.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem the developer account that I used in signing the current app was okay but there was another account logged on in my `Xcode`

that had an expired session.
I deleted the account from the list of accounts and rebuild the app(As I'm using flutter) and it did the magic for me.
Hope it helps